# C# cancellation token taking too long to trigger when referencing a NuGet package library

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, cancellation-token

I currently have some code that references a project library via a NuGet package dependency. If it makes any difference, this NuGet package is hosted on one of our NuGet servers that we created and I'm currently using that as my NuGet source rather than nuget.org.

Let's say my class that calls the method from the NuGet package is called ClassA and has the following code:

```
   public class ClassA {
     // a bunch of code that sets up the configuration

     // call to a periodic transmitter method from the nuget library file
     PeriodicTransmitter transmitter = new PeriodicTransmitter(cancellationTokenSource);

     transmitter.Start();

     stoppingToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
     periodicTransmitter.Stop();
   }
```

Then, within the PeriodicTransmitter file that is referenced in the NuGet package, there is a loop controlled by a cancellation token:

```
public class PeriodicTransmitter {

    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public PeriodicTransmitter(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource = cancellationTokenSource;
        }

    while(!_cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested) { 
       logger.LogInformation("some info");
       
       // operating code

       logger.LogInformation("more info");
    }
}
```

The operating code works just fine, but there is about a 5-6 second delay before the token triggers when I hit ctrl + c in the console to terminate the program. The operating code just keeps looping for a few iterations and logs all the correct information before stopping. I've used cancellation tokens many times under very similar circumstances and I've never experienced this issue.

**I experimented by pasting the library methods into my working file rather than referencing the NuGet package, and the problem magically disappears. My token correctly triggers without delay as soon as I try to terminate the program, but this isn't what I want. I would still like to be able to reference the NuGet package.**

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT: The problem was that I was accidentally initializing the field value _cancellationTokenSource in the PeriodicTransmitter class. After removing that, the console application terminated more quickly. Thanks to @Wyck for the solution.**

Comment: What do I have to do to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Are you certain that the version of the library code that works when you copy directly is the same version as the one being used in the NuGet package?

Comment: @Wyck Sorry about that, I've edited my original post to include a better example. I can't provide the actual code as I do not have the company's permission to share it. Hope that clarifies the issue.

Comment: @devNull Yes, I made sure to update the version that's fetched from our NuGet server. Regardless, that library hasn't been changed in quite some time, so the functionality shouldn't be affected.

Comment: BTW, the PeriodicTransmitter constructor overwrites the field-initialized value -- and that code isn't value C#.  Are you aware of that?

Comment: You don't include the console main or the creation of the CancellationTokenSource.  Also, why do you think the CancellationTokenSource would get set by pressing Ctrl+C in a console application?

Comment: @Wyck Ahh that fixed it, I didn't realize that I was accidentally initializing the _cancellationTokenSource field. Removed it and the program terminates more quickly now. Thanks for the help!